# How to use whois in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

so me and my friend are learning how to code python and came across a unique term 
'whois'
hey said that it extracts data from websites and prints it but we don't know how, we are currently working in python idle and are unable to use this please help by giving us an example, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[link]https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/pywhois

example code after you have installed that module:

```
import whois
whoisdata = whois.whois('google.com')
print(whoisdata.text)
```

notice that whois doesn't scrape webpages, it gives you information about a domain.

More information about whois [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS